# Jump to the middle of an instruction

Tags: assembly, disassembly

I try to test some anti-disassembly techniques. One of which jumps to the middle of an instruction, as in this image:

[image]

When using the code

```
mov     ax, 05EBh
xor     eax, eax
jz      -7
db      0xE8
```

within a small program with NASM I get the following error:

*"error: Win32 COFF does not correctly support relative references to absolute addresses"*

Any idea how to fix that or which tool to use instead of NASM?

Comment: Just curious: why would you *want* to jump to the middle of an instruction?

Comment: Btw, even though that's an offset of -6 (-7 is to the B8), assemblers regard $ as the *start* of the current instruction. For that extra level of confusion I guess. Also, shouldn't that be a `jmp 4`?

Comment: @ScottHunter With that technique you can try to prevent others from disassembling your binaries.

Comment: @harold That confused me a little, too. Well, I got that from a book.

Comment: @SiltCrawler: How does it prevent disassembly?  Its just a jump instruction w/ an unusual (but, apparently, legal) argument.  Might make *understanding* the code more difficult, maybe, but not the disassembly itself.

Comment: @ScottHunter it temporarily misaligns the instruction stream for a trivial disassembler that doesn't take this sort of thing into account. In practice it synchronizes reasonably quickly though.

Comment: @SiltCrawler: But a disassembler just translates the instructions; it doesn't try to follow their execution.  So it shouldn't care how weird a jump target it.

Comment: @ScottHunter that's the problem though, it doesn't follow the branch, and doesn't know that the E8 is not the start of an instruction, and then the disassembly itself will effectively "jump halfway into an instruction" when it advanced by the size of a `call` that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted to jump to the address where the `jz` instruction starts, minus 7 bytes, then you can do that with:

```
jz $-7
```

From the [NASM manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.5):

> `$` evaluates to the assembly position at the beginning of the line containing the expression

Note that the `mov` and `xor` instructions total 6 bytes in size, so you'd be jumping to 1 byte before the start of the `mov`. To jump according to your figure you'd use `jz $-4`

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess it's easy to see, that I'm not experienced yet. So that helped a lot!